# Replace substring inside a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings with a few unclean entries and I want to replace the unclean entries with clean entries

```
list = ['created_DATE', 'column1(case', 'timestamp', 'location(case']
```

I want to get a list that is like this

```
cleanList = ['created_DATE', 'column1', 'timestamp', 'location']
```

I tired the following:

```
str_match = [s for s in list if "(case" in s]     *#find the intersecting elements*
print (str_match)

new=[]
for k in str_match:
   a=k.replace("(case" , "")
   new.append(a)           *#make an list of the words without the substring*
print(new)
```

I am not sure how do I now replace the entries from the new list into the original list. Can someone please help.
Thank you

Comment: Depends exactly what your rule is, but you could use something like `[re.sub("\(.*", "", s) for s in lst]` (where `lst` is your list).

Comment: Don't use the already defined variable `list` as a variable. Use `lst` or `list1` or something similar.

Comment: You can replace elements of the original list while looping over the elements. If an element matches the condition as given by @alani then update the element with the desired string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all occurrences of "case(" from your list's elements, then you could write it like this:

```
list = ['created_DATE', 'column1(case', 'timestamp', 'location(case']
clean = []

for n in list:
    clean.append(n.replace("(case", ""))
    
print(clean)
```

Comment: Don't redefine the already python defined variable `list`. Use a different variable name. And, while this works, [@alani's comment/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73123568/replace-substring-inside-a-list#comment129147197_73123568) is a much cleaner 1 line code that also uses regex to match all occurrences of "(somestring"

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a new list `clean` as told by [@alani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73123568/replace-substring-inside-a-list#comment129147197_73123568):

```
import re

myList = ['created_DATE', 'column1(case', 'timestamp', 'location(case']

clean = [re.sub("\(.*", "", s) for s in myList]

print(clean)
```

or iterate over elements of myList and update in place

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
  if "(case" in myList[i]:
    myList[i] = myList[i].replace("(case" , "")
print(myList)
```

Comment: Thanks  @sherminator35 . I actually did the second method and it worked. Regex is a smart idea and thank you for your quick inputs.